# file uploaded with name in python django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I was using this code:

```
  def saveUploadedInventory(self, inventory_file,user_id): 
      with open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','wb+') as destination:
          for chunk in inventory_file.chunks():
              destination.write(chunk)

      reader = csv.reader(open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','rb'))
```

file with this name uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv is uploaded successfully

but I want to upload the same file in different directory with its actual name which is coming from client.

I try following code:

```
def saveUploadedInventory(self, inventory_file,user_id): 
    with open(''.join(inventory_file),'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in inventory_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    reader = csv.reader(open('inventory_file','rb'))
```

but It is gives following error:

> Exception Type:   IOError
>
> Exception Value:   [Errno 36] File name too
> long: 'Se .. .. . .

Comment: What is the output of ''.join(inventory_file)? It appears to be something really long, when what you actually want is just the name.

Comment: I get error `file name too long` and then all data of file is printed over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to open the name of the file, not join it's content:

```
def saveUploadedInventory(self, inventory_file,user_id): 
    with open(inventory_file.name,'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in inventory_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    reader = csv.reader(open(inventory_file.name,'rb'))
```

`open` takes the name of the file that you wish to open, so you should use the name provided in the `name` field of `inventory_file`.

From [UploadedFile documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.name):

> UploadedFile.name
>
> ```
> The name of the uploaded file (e.g. my_file.txt).
> ```

Comment: and how to write that file in different directory instead of project foder

Comment: To write in different folder `with open(/path/to/inventory_file.name,'wb+') as destination`.